# Firebase Unhandled Promise Rejection when querying database

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I'm doing a project where I use redux to manage the app with thunk middleware. However when I call below function from actions it gives me,

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): Error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.
```

**Code**

```
1 export const submitEmail=(email)=>{
2   return(dispatch) =>{ // Still did not use dispatch
3     val = getData(email);
4     console.log(val);
5   }
6 };
7
8 const getData = async(email)=>{
9  let usersRef =  await firebase.database().ref('Users')
10 usersRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).on("value", (snapshot) => {
11   snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
12      return snap.val();
13    })});
14 }
```

So when I run `submitEmail` function, value of `val` gives me a promise before getting this warning.

```
Promise {_40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null}
```

**Question**

I want to **wait** until querying the database and get the data in json format.

**Note**

This happens because `firebase.database().ref('Users')` does not return a promise. But how can I then get `var` value in `line 4` after evaluating `getData` function?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users')
```

Does not do anything with the database yet. It merely creates a reference to a potential `/Users` reference in the database. This is a purely client-side operation, so does not need to return a promise.

Loading data from the database is done by calling `on()` or `once()`. Between these `once()` only loads the data once, and returns a promise. On the other hand `on()` starts to continuously listen for the data. Since this is a continuous process, it never completes and thus `on()` can't return a promise.

What you want is likely:

```
export const submitEmail=(email)=>{
  return(dispatch) =>{
    val = getData(email);
    console.log(val);
  }
};

const getData = async(email)=>{
  let usersRef = firebase.database().ref('Users')
  let snapshot = await usersRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once("value")
  let userSnapshot
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    userSnapshot = child
  });
  return userSnapshot
}
```